# Installing Qgis 2.16 on Windows 10 - MSVCP120.dll?

Tags: installation, qgis-2.14, qgis-2.16, windows-10

For some problems in my PC it was need to restore Windows 10 and when I tried to launch Qgis (2.16 and 2.14) a message from Windows appeared (see image in attached; sorry, the message is in italian):

[image]

So I decided to Unistall Osgeo directory and install it again using OSGeo4w install. Everything worked fine untill it was installing qgis-common. At that moment the previous Windows message appeared again. After OK, installation continued and at the end appeared:

> OSGEO4W message - Postinstall script error "Package: qgis-common,
>   qgis-common.bat code-1073741521".

So I decided to install Qgis 2.14 but I had always the same problems.
Somebody can help me? .

Comment: check these other threads: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=MSVCP120.dll

Comment: installation uses 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: mmmmmm, 64 bits!

Comment: I imagined, clean up everything and try reinstalling the whole 32-bit and as administrator

Answer (score 3):

It's too late I imagine but for someone esle with the same problem.
https://support.native-instruments.com/hc/en-us/articles/209571689-Windows-Error-Message-Missing-MSVCP120-dll-File
It worked for me in W7

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.   Links can change or disappear over time, so can you please [edit] your answer and include the solution in your answer (and use your link as reference). Link-only answers may be deleted.

Comment: It worked to me in W7 Ultimate 64 Bits. Thanks, user91438!

Answer (score 0):

You can try another distro by NextGIS with autoupdates feature. Get it here: http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

Some details can be found here: http://nextgis.com/blog/qgis17/

[image: Installer window]