# DLL errors after installing QField on Windows 10

Tags: installation, error, qfield, windows-10, dll

On the working machine with Window 10 Enterprise Version 1909 (Build 18363.2094) I installed the QField which I could get from here : https://qfield.org/docs/en/install/index.html

However, I am getting a bundle of system DLL errors after launching the QField:

> The code execution cannot continue because `sentry.dll` was not found.
> Reinstalling the program may resolve the issue.

> The code execution cannot continue because `qgis_core.dll` was not found.
> Reinstalling the program may resolve the issue.

> The code execution cannot continue because `proj.dll` was not found.
> Reinstalling the program may resolve the issue.

> The code execution cannot continue because `gdal304.dll` was not found.
> Reinstalling the program may resolve the issue.

[image: error1]

[image: error2]

[image: error3]

[image: error4]

I have not tried yet to reinstall the QField as suggested in the error box.

I have already seen this thread (a bit related) [Installing Qgis 2.16 on Windows 10 - MSVCP120.dll?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214646/installing-qgis-2-16-on-windows-10-msvcp120-dll), but without much success.

Perhaps it is a case that was mentioned in the documentation :

> Windows support is currently in beta status. Download the latest
> development builds and leave us a note how it works.

so, I do have to leave a note : https://www.opengis.ch/#contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to follow this issue from 03.05.2022 on the GitHub : https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/2856, where core developer @MatthiasKuhn stated:

> Thank you for reporting. We have deleted the broken releases for now
> and are investigating the problem.

Another user on GitHub pointed at:

> I'm having the same problem here. The latest version that worked was
> [2.0.14](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v2.0.14).

To find the latest working version, check the: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases